# Different training method for encoder-decoder model

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, sequence-to-sequence

Trying to learn the encoder-decoder model for some NLP problems.

I am referring to [this Keras tutorial](https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html).

During the model training phase, this tutorial just uses the following:

```
model.fit([encoder_input_data, decoder_input_data], decoder_target_data,
          batch_size=batch_size,
          epochs=epochs)
```

I understand this logic. But the confusion is in some other tutorials for EXACTLY THE SAME PROBLEM. For example, in Tensorflow's documentation for [NMT with Attention](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/nmt_with_attention) the training_phase is very different where they use custom training loops with a custom train step and calling the step for every batch manually.

The question is are these 2 different training methods which should be used in particular cases OR its the same training method with 2 different forms of implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is a straight forward use of API while the other one gives you much better control on training. If you are experimenting, it is good to go with a custom training loop so you can control the various things that happen to your model's training.

But, if you want to just train a model and not experiment with it much, save time and go for the straight forward method of training.

Both are same but one gives you much more control.